# Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant? (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

**use redux for calling api from django . Django server running. We make store like :**

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { productListReducer } from "./reducers/productReducers";


const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducer,
});

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

**and my product Reducers is :**

```
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/productConstants";

export const productListReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, products: [] };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, products: action.payload };
    case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**ProductAction :**

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/productConstants";

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products/");
    console.log("Loading..")
    console.log(data)

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { listProducts } from "../actions/productActions";

const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts())
    


  }, [dispatch]);
```

When we calling api using useEffect we not get the api data . we get empty data and also get
Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant. Please help me to solve this question .

in here i give u some photo ,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe the action types  are `undefined` , Can you check the imported action types

Comment: Either thunk middleware not recognized properly, or action type constants being undefined, as other comment says. But your linter/build tools should catch that already. Btw having the state change its shape between actions is not recommended. The initial state should have everything already (loading as false and error null for example).

Comment: Then please how can i solve it ? i'm new at redux